Barcolor and Trailingstop plot is not executed, and I don't know how to code exact multiple close condition
I'm new trader who started to use Pinesctipt a few days ago. I found two indicators in TradingView community: UT bot indicatior and STC indidcator. UT bot is indicator whose core idea is the breakout of ATR trailingstop, and STC indicator is oscillator that uses difference of fast MA and Slow MA. I tried to make strategy using those.
I made code that united UT bot and STC, but I met a few problems.

In debug process, I found Trailingstop plot is not visible. I meant that there is red line on the chart when Trailingstop is below close price, and green line when Trailingstop is over close price. I guess the problem that setted barcolor is not visible on the chart is based on the same cause as Trailingstop plotting.

and I have difficulty with correctly coding strategy-close condition. I think Long position is closed when STC >=75 (Profit) or when close price is under (entry_bar_close - entry_bar_Trailingstop), but I don't know what function to use under 'else'.


Can you let me know what causes invisible trailingstop plot? and Can you let me know how to code multiple close condition?
Here is code of what I thought of:
//@version=5
strategy(title="UT Bot Strategy + STC", overlay = false,process_orders_on_close = true, initial_capital = 100000)

//UT bot
// Inputs
ATRmultiple = input.float(2, title = "Key Vaule")
ATRperiod = input(6, title = "ATR Period")

//ATR
ATR = ta.atr(ATRperiod)
nLoss = ATRmultiple * ATR

//Trailingstop and Plot > Problem Occured!
source = close

var float Trailingstop = na
if source > nz(Trailingstop[1],0) and (source[1] > nz(Trailingstop[1],0))
    Trailingstop := math.max(Trailingstop[1],source - nLoss)
else if (source < nz(Trailingstop[1],0)) and (source[1] < nz(Trailingstop[1],0))
    Trailingstop := math.min(Trailingstop[1],source + nLoss)
else if (source > Trailingstop[1])
    Trailingstop := source - nLoss
else
    Trailingstop := source + nLoss

var color trailingstop_color = na
if close > Trailingstop
    trailingstop_color := color.red
else
    trailingstop_color := color.green
plot(Trailingstop,color=trailingstop_color,linewidth=2, force_overlay = true)
 
//Set Buy and Sell condition of UT bot
ema   = ta.ema(source,1)
above = ta.crossover(ema, Trailingstop)
below = ta.crossover(Trailingstop, ema)

buy  = source > Trailingstop and above 
sell = source < Trailingstop and below

//Set Bar color condition
barbuy  = source > Trailingstop 
barsell = source < Trailingstop 


//STC indicator
STC_Period = input(12, 'Length')
Fast_MA_Period = input(26, 'FastLength')
Slow_MA_Period = input(50, 'SlowLength')

//finding base1 for STC
MA_Difference(Bar_Data, Fast_MA_Period, Slow_MA_Period) =>
    fastMA = ta.ema(Bar_Data, Fast_MA_Period)
    slowMA = ta.ema(Bar_Data, Slow_MA_Period)
    MA_Difference = fastMA - slowMA
    MA_Difference

//finding base1 ratio
STC(STC_Period, Fast_MA_Period, Slow_MA_Period) =>
    Smoothing = input(0.5)
    var STC_Base1_Ratio = 0.0
    var STC_Base2 = 0.0
    var STC_Base2_Ratio = 0.0
    var STC_Base3_Ratio = 0.0
    STC_Base1 = MA_Difference(close, Fast_MA_Period, Slow_MA_Period) 
    STC_Base1_lowest = ta.lowest(STC_Base1, STC_Period) 
    STC_Base1_Range = ta.highest(STC_Base1, STC_Period) - STC_Base1_lowest
    STC_Base1_Ratio := STC_Base1_Range > 0 ? ((STC_Base1 - STC_Base1_lowest) / STC_Base1_Range) * 100 : nz(STC_Base1_Ratio[1])

//finding base2 ratio
    STC_Base2 := na(STC_Base2[1]) ? STC_Base1_Ratio : STC_Base2[1] + Smoothing * (STC_Base1_Ratio - STC_Base2[1])
    STC_Base2_lowest = ta.lowest(STC_Base2, STC_Period)
    STC_Base2_Range = ta.highest(STC_Base2, STC_Period) - STC_Base2_lowest
    STC_Base2_Ratio := STC_Base2_Range > 0 ? ((STC_Base2 - STC_Base2_lowest) / STC_Base2_Range) * 100 : nz(STC_Base2_Ratio[1])

//finding base3 ratio
    STC_Base3_Ratio := na(STC_Base3_Ratio[1]) ? STC_Base2_Ratio : STC_Base3_Ratio[1] + Smoothing * (STC_Base2_Ratio - STC_Base3_Ratio[1])
    STC_Base3_Ratio


stc = STC(STC_Period, Fast_MA_Period, Slow_MA_Period)

// Bar Color
barcolor(barbuy  ? color.green : na)
barcolor(barsell ? color.red   : na)

//Entry and Close
entry_bar_distance = bar_index - strategy.opentrades.entry_bar_index(strategy.opentrades-1)

BuyCondition = buy and (stc <=25)
BuyCloseCondition1 = ta.crossover(stc, 75)
BuyCloseCondition2 = ta.crossunder(source, Trailingstop[entry_bar_distance])

SellCondition = sell and (stc >= 75)
SellCloseCondition1 = ta.crossunder(stc, 25)
SellCloseCondition2 = ta.crossover(source, Trailingstop[entry_bar_distance])


if BuyCondition
    strategy.entry("Long",strategy.long)
if BuyCloseCondition1
    strategy.close("Long")
else if BuyCloseCondition2
    strategy.close("Long")
// else
//     ???

Can you teach how to code in this kind of situation?
